# How can I get back my ColdFusion 2016 Server Updates page?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I updated Coldfusion 2016 with Update 9 earlier today (Feb 22, 2019). Now, when I log into the CF Administrator and visit

- *Server Update > Updates*

I get the universal error handler page we set for our website we set in

- *Server Settings > Settings > Error Handlers > Site-Wide Error Handler*

I can click around the CF Administrator page links on the left menu and the error only comes up when I click on server updates.

Do you know how I can check if the update was successful? Can you tell me how to get my Updates page back?

Comment: I figured it out.

I ran the update from the browser while remoted in to the server. The "run as" account we use does not have rights based on the lockdown manual. I had to re-do the update manually as an admin via command line.

Comment: You should post the solution as an "answer" so it's more visible (answering your own question is allowed).